# Does the mod location matter for special effects on armor?

Tags: fallout-4

I found a piece of armor that reduces damage from super mutants by 15%.  Does this apply to all super mutant damage or only damage when they strike the limb that wears the armor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mod effects from armor are global. So if you've got a piece of armor that reduces damage from Super Mutants by 15% then this is a global 15% reduction in damage from Super Mutants regardless of where they hit you.

Comment: Do you know if mods stack?  Does having two pieces of it mean 30% reduction?

Comment: @z' Pocketed mod stacks. That is the only one that I have tested though, so not sure if the others stack.

Comment: This answer was my assumption. Have you tested this somehow, though? Or know of someone who has?